# AWS CLI - S3 how to replace a folder atomically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So,

Let's say I have a folder called **/example** in S3. This folder contains a file called **a.txt**.

using AWS CLI, how do I upload a local folder, also called **example**, and replace the current S3 **/example** atomically. The local folder contains a file called **b.txt**.

So, I want the behaviour to be that the new S3 **/example** folder only contains **b.txt**.

Basically, is there a way to **atomically** replace an entire folder in S3 with a new one via the AWS CLI?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

No, you can't do that.

For starters, S3 is an eventual consistent platform. That means that right after you do a write, you can still get old data back from S3. Practically, this converges quickly (seconds), but there is no upper bound. (They do provide consistency guarantees is some sequence of operations, but generally speaking, it's not strongly consistent)

Secondly, S3 does not have a concept of "folder" or "directory". S3 namespace is flat. The only thing that *object* `/example/a.txt` and `/example/b.txt` have in common is that they start with the same string, just like `/foobar.txt` and `/foobaz.txt` begin with the same string. (The User Interface does cheat a bit by treating the `/` character differently, and giving the illusion of directories)

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: Thanks. What about replacing an individual file atomically? Will at any point the file not exist?

Comment: @KarlYoung overwrites of existing individual objects are always atomic.  There is no time when the object being overwritten will not exist, or be corrupt or partial. The consistency model says that subsequent downloads may result in the new object or the old object for a brief time, but it will always be one object or the other, intact, and whichever file is being downloaded will download completely.  If an overwriting upload is interrupted for any reason, the new content is discarded and the old object is unaffected.

Comment: S3 is now consistent. However, atomic replacement of folders cannot be done as S# is based on object paths. If you can afford it you can issue 2 commands `s3 rm bucket/example/ --recursive` `s3 cp /local/example bucket/example/`